# How to unhide magento2 product image programmatically?

Tags: magento2, gallery

I have programmatically added image to `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table and to `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`, and `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity` as well, i see my image in product catalog list, but it tells me the image is hidden.

What attribute i should change to unhide it? i have tried to update varchar attributes `small_image` `image` `thumbnail` and `swatch_image` but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is required to set `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` `disabled` column to `0` and it appears

Answer (score 5):

Say you wanted to make sure that all "Base" images were unhidden. You could run a SQL Query like:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` SET `disabled` = 0 WHERE `value_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `value_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` WHERE `value` IN ( 
        SELECT `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id` = ( 
            SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = "image" AND `frontend_label` = "Base" LIMIT 1 ) ) )
```

To explain, working **backwards**:

First, find the attribute id for "Base" images:

```
SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = "image" AND `frontend_label` = "Base" LIMIT 1
```

Second, find all images with that attribute id:

```
SELECT `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id` = (...the resulting id from above)
```

Third, find the ids of all the gallery items:

```
SELECT `value_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` WHERE `value` IN (...the resulting values)
```

And finally, update the disabled value to 0:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` SET `disabled` = 0 WHERE `value_id` IN (...the resulting ids)
```

Now chain that all up into the original SQL and you're all set!

You could also do this with other images, but examine the eav_attribute table to make sure you're searching for the right values. The small image for example would have an attribute_code of "small_image" and a frontend_label of "Small".

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` and `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` the `disabled`-column to `0` and apply it.

or:

Use Below Sql Query For Enable All The Hidden Product Images

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` SET `disabled`= 0 WHERE DISABLED = 1
```

and

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` SET `disabled`= 0 WHERE DISABLED = 1
```

Comment: This is the better answer.